# Insert records into a table with IF statement from a temp in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, aggregation, insert-update

I have a table `table1` that has some columns, which has to be calculated and moved into another table `table2` based on some conditions. To meet the conditions, I created a temp table `#ttemp` and altered the temp table to with creating two new variables `var1` and `var2` to set some values based on different columns and later check those conditions. If conditions pass, I do some aggregation and then later I would insert into `table2` that will have aggregated columns.

First, create the `#temp` table and variables from `table1`.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #ttemp
FROM table1

alter table #ttemp add var1 int
alter table #ttemp add var2 int

update #ttemp set var1 = -1

update #ttemp set var1 = 1
where error <> 0 and var1 = -1

update #ttemp var2 = -1
```

Next, values of `var1` column and `var2` columns' values from `#temp` table (`var1 = 0` and `var2 = -1`) and calculate average of `cus_request`, `cus_stay` and put them in a new temp table `#ttemp2`.

```
IF var2 = -1 and var1 = 0
   BEGIN
   select y.id, y.avg(cus_request) as r_avg, y.avg(cust_stay) as s_avg
   INTO #ttemp2
   FROM #ttemp as y

   UPDATE l
   SET l.cus_request_avg = t.r_avg, l.cust_stay_avg = t.s_avg
   FROM table2 as l
   inner join #ttemp2 as t
   t.id = l.id

END
```

My problem is, my IF statement is not working and if I just run the `select` statements and `update` statement it works fine, but after update statement, it I get `0 rows affected` as conditions do not meet. I am using `update` instead of `insert` statement. How can insert records into `table2`?

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Where is your BEGIN?

Comment: Can you post the full query? I am not really getting how your IF fits in. With an IF you want to be comparing a value, not a column. What you have done there could be achieved by a WHERE clause I'd imagine.

Comment: @Leonidas199x I am comparing values from those `var1` and `var2` columns. I am an novice in SQL Server. Do you mean that I can set `var1` and `var2`'s value comparison in `where` clause?

Comment: Your pseudocode is so vague it is really hard to figure out what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @SeanLange Okay, let me edit the post. Is it possible to do IF statement and insert records? Sorry, I am trying to understand SQL's IF ELSE logics!

Comment: @i.n.n.m well, I think it could be a possibility based off of what you have posted. In an IF you would compare two values, not columns, so unless that is in a loop, I can't make sense of it.

Comment: IF ELSE in t-sql is no different than anywhere else. IF SomeConditionIsTrue DoSomething Else DoSomethingElse

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misusing IF.

IF would compare two values, not look through two columns and pick out the data where the conditions are met.

I think you could achieve what you are after with a WHERE clause:

```
   SELECT avg(y.cus_request) AS r_avg, avg(y.cust_stay) AS s_avg
   INTO #ttemp2 as t2
   FROM #ttemp as y
   WHERE    y.var2 = -1 AND y.var1 = 0

   UPDATE l
   SET l.cus_request_avg = t.r_avg, 
       l.cust_stay_avg = t.s_avg
   FROM table2 as l
   inner join #ttemp2 as t ON t.id = l.id
```

To answer the question in the comments....

To just insert into the table, it is:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
        (
            cus_request_avg ,
            cust_stay_avg
        )
SELECT      t.r_avg         ,
            t.s_avg
FROM        #ttemp2     AS t;
```

To insert only where the records do not exist in table2:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
        (
            cus_request_avg ,
            cust_stay_avg
        )
SELECT      t.r_avg         ,
            t.s_avg
FROM        #ttemp2     AS t
LEFT JOIN   table2      AS l ON t.id = l.id
WHERE       l.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I was on the process of editing my question from comments above, but i could edit in words, not in my code much as that is pretty much I had. Let me try this. This might be the way to go!

Comment: @i.n.n.m have made some amendments, the aliasing needed a little attention.

Comment: Yes, my error - apologies. What are you joining #ttemp2 to table2 on?

Comment: `where` clause works, however, quick question if I have to insert realtime as soon as I calculate average, how can I use insert into the `table2`? instead of using update? (Say I don'r have any data in table2)